# Most frequent kept size per user

Tags: r

unfortunately the new month brought my some new problems I´m not able to solve alone - I want to list the size every user returned [returnShipment=1] the most. When 2 or more sizes have the same occurency it should write an "-"

Tried it already like this but I´m stuck on how to solve it ;)

```
tmp <- with(DB, tapply(size, customerID, returnShipment, function(x) {
  tbl <- table(x)
  most <- which(tbl == max(tbl) & returnShipment == "No")
  if (length(most) > 1) return('-') else return(names(tbl)[most])
}))
DB$mostKeptSize <- tmp[DB$customerID]
```

Expected outcome(update with returned Items instead of retained[ItemReturned =="Yes"]):

```
mostreturnedSize = c("-", "retained all items", "42", "-", "-", "42", "retained all items", "retained all items", "-", "-")
```

(user 1: returned size "m"once & size "xxl"once
user 2: returned no items
user 3: returned size "42" once)

Data:

```
DB <- data.frame(orderID  = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),     
orderDate = c("1.1.14","1.1.14","1.1.14","1.1.14","2.1.14", "2.1.14","2.1.14","2.1.14","2.1.14","2.1.14"),  
itemID = c(2,3,2,5,12,4,2,3,1,5),  
size = c("m", "l", 42, "xxl", "m", 42, 39, "m", "m", 44),
customerID = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1),
ItemReturned = c('No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No'))
```

Hope you're able to show me what´s wrong or show me another possibility to solve the problem.

That´s what I have so far:

```
tab = table(mydata[mydata$returnShipment == 0, c("customerID", "size")])
maxes = max.col(tab, "first")
ifelse(rowSums(tab == tab[cbind(seq_len(nrow(tab)), maxes)]) > 1, 
       "-", 
       colnames(tab)[maxes])[mydata$customerID]
```

Comment: alexis_laz solution works perfectly fine for both previous and the updated data.

Comment: but it´s not working for my original data set:don´t really know where the problem is...

Comment: Probably because your original data set is a `data.table` class. Try `DB  <- as.data.frame(DB)` and then run alexis code again.

Comment: no, it´s a data frame and all- the instances are the same classes ( customerID is numeric; size is a factor and ItemReturned is a factor, too ( the only diffence is, that it´s "o" instead of "no" and "1" instead of "yes": maybe this is the problem?

Comment: Could be the reason, yes.

Comment: do you have an idea, what need to be changed in the solution of alexis_laz that it works?

Comment: Did you try changing to `DB$ItemReturned == 0` ?

Comment: Yes- I tried: see my solution in question....sth must be wrong, cause it shows me NA for all...(mydata=DB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by the edits, but what you describe seems to be achieved with the following modifications in the original answer:

```
DB[["customerID"]] = factor(DB[["customerID"]]) #I guess it should be a factor    
tab = table(DB[DB$ItemReturned == "Yes", c("customerID", "size")])
maxes = max.col(tab, "first")
ans = ifelse(rowSums(tab == tab[cbind(seq_len(nrow(tab)), maxes)]) > 1, 
             "-", 
             colnames(tab)[maxes])
ans[rowSums(tab) == 0] = "retained all items"
unname(ans[DB$customerID])
#[1] "-"                  "retained all items" "42"                
# [4] "-"                  "-"                  "42"                
# [7] "retained all items" "retained all items" "-"                 
#[10] "-"
```

Comment: Works fine, but how can I print out "returned no items", when the customer returned no items? Do you have an idea?

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner : You mean, print "returned no items" instead of "-"? If so, simply change the "-" in `ifelse`. Or, if you want `ItemReturned == "No"` change the respective line above. If I'm misunderstanding what you're saying, could you edit the question with a specific example?

Comment: It´s all good-except the case, when a user returns NO item (kept all): then I want a "returned no items" Will update above in a minute...

Comment: updated the expected output + the data set (column ItemReturned)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with...

```
DB <- data.frame(orderID  = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),     
                 orderDate = c("1.1.14","1.1.14","1.1.14","1.1.14","2.1.14", "2.1.14","2.1.14","2.1.14","2.1.14","2.1.14"),  
                 itemID = c(2,3,2,5,12,4,2,3,1,5),  
                 size = c("m", "l", 42, "xxl", "m", 42, 39, "m", "m", 44),
                 customerID = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1),
                 ItemReturned = c('No', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'No'))
theMost <- function(ID){
  df <- subset(DB, customerID==ID & ItemReturned=="No")
  tbl <- table(df$size)
  theMax <- max(tbl)
  theSizes <- names(tbl)[tbl==theMax]
  theSizes <- paste(theSizes, collapse="-")
  return(theSizes)
}
lapply(unique(DB$customerID), theMost)
```

Comment: This returns `"l-m"` for the second element, not `"-"`

Comment: I don´t really understand the result - and how can I integrate it to my existing data set?

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
res <- unsplit( lapply(split(DB, DB$customerID), function(x) {
            tbl <- table(factor(x$size[x$ItemReturned=='No']))
            x$mostKeptsize <- if(sum(tbl==max(tbl))>1) '-' 
                     else names(which.max(tbl)); x}),
                    DB$customerID)
res$mostKeptsize
#[1] "m"  "-"  "42" "m"  "m"  "42" "-"  "-"  "m"  "m"
```

#### Update

Based on the new data

```
 res <- unsplit(lapply(split(DB, DB$customerID), function(x) {
          if(any(x$ItemReturned=='No')) {
          tbl <- table(factor(x$size[x$ItemReturned=='No']))
           x$mostKeptsize <- if(sum(tbl==max(tbl))>1) '-' 
           else names(which.max(tbl)) } 
        else x$mostKeptsize <-rep('returned all', nrow(x));x}),
        DB$customerID)

 res$mostKeptsize
 #[1] "m"            "-"            "returned all" "m"            "m"           
 #[6] "returned all" "-"            "-"            "m"            "m"
```

Comment: Works fine most of the time-but when a customer returned all of his ordered items: the most kept size is a series of numbers (beginning with "270569" and ongoing). Do you have an idea how to give out an "-" too?

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner  Please do update your post with an example that shows the given problem.

Comment: I added a pic of it down the site

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner  Pic's are not that helpful as it is not possible to copy data from the pic

Comment: well-I changed the data set up above.

Comment: it gives out for the second user "l-m" now:and thats the problem

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner Okay, let me try it.  `l-m` is not an option in my solution

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner If you have a customerID with only "Yes", especially for ID 3, what do you want to return?

Comment: when it´s ony "Yes" I wanna return a "returned all" or an "-" too

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner  Updated the solution.  Please check if that helps

Comment: works now! Thanks-but how can I integrate/add the column "mostKeptsize" into my existing dataset and delete the "res" dataset afterwards ?

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner You can check `res` and `DB`, it should be the same except the `mostKeptsize` column

Comment: yes, that´s true-but i want to ingrate mostKeptsize into DB and delete res afterwards:how can I do it?

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner Then you can just update that as `DB <- unsplit(....)` instead of `res`

Comment: Works! Thanks buddy-I need the same for ItemReturned==Yes: but when I change it to yes: it´s not working properly-shows me "returned a, when the costumer kept al Items:see edit above. Can you help me?

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner Looks like alexis_laz already changed the code.  Wouldn't that help for your new edit?

Answer (score 0):

I used `dplyr` to try and make the code more human readable.  The function getMostFrequent first strips returned items, then groups by the size variable, gets the count of each, makes a new column which evaluates if that size is the max, filters to only those rows and keeps only the size variable.  Then it checks - if there's more than one row, return a "-" otherwise return the most frequent size as a character (to make other operations easier in the future).

Now - how to apply this: I first used split() which takes your original data and turns it into a list, one for each customerID.  This has the advantage of naming the elements of the with the userID - order isn't important.  I use lapply to apply the function to each element of the list which returns a list with named elements.  I then extract this into a single data.frame with customerID and most common size.  If you really want this to be a vector that matches up with the original, you could do some recasting of variables and a `left_join` in `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

getMostFrequent = function(x) {
  data = x %>%
    filter(ItemReturned == "No") %>%
    group_by(size) %>%
    summarise(Count = n()) %>%
    mutate(mostFrequent = ifelse(Count==max(Count),1,0)) %>%
    filter(mostFrequent == 1) %>%
    select(size)
  if(nrow(data) > 1){
    return("-")
  } else {
    return(as.character(data$size))
  }
}

j = lapply(with(DB,split(DB,customerID)),getMostFrequent)
data.frame(customerID = names(j),mostCommonSize=unlist(j))

  customerID mostCommonSize
1          1              m
2          2              -
3          3             42
```